# How can i tell if is complicated function is an injection/surjection/both?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

My teacher gave us a complicated function and told us to prove whether it is a surjection or injection or both

$f(x,y,z) = 326x^{32} + log_232 - z^6 + {y^3} - 3452542  $

He said that although it looks difficult, there is quite an easy way to tell and prove it. I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Ask yourself how many solutions $-z^6+y^3=0$ has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function only depends of $x $ and $z $ by a pair power which makes it clear that $f(x,y,z) = f(-x,y,z) $ and that $f(x,y,z) = f(x,y,-z)$ thus it is not injective. Is it surjective?

Can you make $k = 326x^{32} + log_232 - z^6 + {y^3} - 3452542$ for any $k $? Set $x = z =0$ to get

$k = log_232 + {y^3} - 3452542 \iff \sqrt[3]{k -log_33 + 3452542} = y$

So it is surjective.

Comment: Wow, didn't know it was that easy XD.

Comment: When you have a complex problem, try to make it easier. Dealing with 3 variables at the same time is something that is **not** simple so your first attempt should be to tackle each variable separately

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider restricting the function to the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, and $z$-axis (i.e., consider the three functions $x\mapsto f(x,0,0)$, $y\mapsto f(0,y,0)$, and $z\mapsto f(0,0,z)$ which are functions of of one variable).